# How to upload files to password protected HTTPS site using CURL?

Tags: upload, curl

How can I upload files to a HTTPS site using CURL?

The site is also password protected.

What's the command line used to upload for that particular site?

Comment: Upload how? A custom Web form invoked with POST? HTTP PUT request? mat's solution will work only in the second case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can,

```
$ curl --user login:password --upload-file your.file.txt https://the.url/where/that/should/go
```

You may need to add `--insecure` if you don't want cURL to check the certificate chain.

Comment: Can I omit `--upload-file `?